# SharePoint Document Library : Upload document option does not apply document content type template

Tags: document, content, template

I need to upload an existing document say "Doc1.docx" with some content,header and footer  in a sharepoint document library using "Upload Document" option. I also have a Document template associated with content type say "DocTemp.docx" . When i upload the document "Doc1.docx" , i want the template "DocTemp.docx" to applied on document "Doc1.docx" .

But selecting content type template is not applied to the uploaded document even after selection. How do I accompalish this task?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a document or form library, you can set a default file template for that library. When someone creates a new file in the library, the default template opens in the appropriate program. For example in a document library, you can set a Microsoft Office Word 2010 template. When someone creates a new file in that document library, the template opens in Word.

The contenttype will not be applied for the uploaded document it is only applied when using the New document > Contenttype button.